# Editing XML From SQL Query Using XML-DML

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-dml

I have an XML column in my MSSQL database whose schema looks similar to this:

```
<Form>
   <Version>1000</Version>
   <OtherValues />
</Form>
```

And I need to manually change (via script) all rows' `Version` numbers to 1001. Upon searching, I can infer that I'm going to be using the `.modify` XPath function but all examples I've found have been for inserting nodes, not editing them.

Could someone shed some light on how to do this?

Comment: For SQL-Server the correct language for update is XML-DML.

Comment: Noted, changed the question title to reflect that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example data setup:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    Id int
    , X xml
)

INSERT @t VALUES ( 1, '
<Form>
   <Version>1000</Version>
   <OtherValues />
</Form>
'
)

INSERT @t VALUES ( 2, '
<Form>
   <Version>1000</Version>
   <OtherValues />
</Form>
'
)
```

Pre-change data:

```
SELECT * FROM @t

Id          X
----------- ------------------------------------------------------------
1           <Form><Version>1000</Version><OtherValues /></Form>
2           <Form><Version>1000</Version><OtherValues /></Form>
```

**Data update**:

```
UPDATE @t
SET X.modify('
replace value of 
    (/Form/Version[.="1000"]/text())[1]
with
    "1001"
')
```

Post-change data:

```
SELECT * FROM @t

Id          X
----------- ------------------------------------------------------------
1           <Form><Version>1001</Version><OtherValues /></Form>
2           <Form><Version>1001</Version><OtherValues /></Form>
```

---

Things to note:

- `replace value of` requires that the 'to-be-replaced' expression identifies a "statical singleton", ie the *parser* must be able to work out that it refers to a **single** value - hence the `[1]`
- Only **one** node (per row) will ever be modified by `.modify`! So if you have multiple XML nodes in a single row, you will have to iterate manually

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch, AakashM.